# How can I write a file in UTF-8 format?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iconv, mbstring

I have bunch of files that are not in UTF-8 encoding and I'm converting a site to UTF-8 encoding.

I'm using simple script for files that I want to save in UTF-8, but the files are saved in old encoding:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$fpath = "folder";
$d = dir($fpath);
while (False !== ($a = $d->read()))
{
    if ($a != '.' and $a != '..')
    {
        $npath = $fpath . '/' . $a;

        $data = file_get_contents($npath);

        file_put_contents('tempfolder/' . $a, $data);
    }
}
```

How can I save files in UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*[file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)* and *[file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)* will not magically convert encoding.

You have to convert the string explicitly; for example with *[iconv()](http://php.net/iconv)* or *[mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)*.

Try this:

```
$data = file_get_contents($npath);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING');
file_put_contents('tempfolder/' . $a, $data);
```

Or alternatively, with PHP's stream filters:

```
$fd = fopen($file, 'r');
stream_filter_append($fd, 'convert.iconv.UTF-8/OLD-ENCODING');
stream_copy_to_stream($fd, fopen($output, 'w'));
```

Comment: What is $a variable on line 3 of first example?

Comment: In case of using stream_filter_append:
OLD-ENCODING/UTF-8

Answer (score 101):

Add BOM: UTF-8

```
file_put_contents($myFile, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $content);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... short and sweet, and works!

Comment: There is a distinction between creating a file recognized as an UTF-8 and converting the content which goes to that file. A plain text file without special characters has the same content as UTF-8 without BOM, also parsers which might be processing your text have an encoding option. PHP uses UTF-8 itself, so if you see text OK but file does not seem to be UTF-8, chances are the text is UTF-8 and adding BOM is all you need. But, it's not converting. This problem is seen often, because PHP is lazy adding BOM, but it itself is expecting it on input.

Comment: I had a slightly different issue than the OP, but this solved my issue.  I didn't use file_put_contents, but instead used header to download the file immediately.  The data was already in UTF-8 in the database, but it wasn't working the CSV download.  This worked great.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this solution is the BOM sits there in front of the first character in the file and can interfere with text operations such as sorting lines, cursor movement around the BOM, etc.

Answer (score 30):

```php
<?php
    function writeUTF8File($filename, $content) {
        $f = fopen($filename, "w");
        # Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark
        fwrite($f, pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf));
        fwrite($f, $content);
        fclose($f);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I was trying to create a php download script in order to use UTF-8 for danish characters, this is what it was missing, ty

Comment: It also works to UTF-16 but with that bytes: fwrite($f, pack("CC",0xff,0xfe));

Comment: @tSr you're a life saver

Answer (score 5):

[Iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to the rescue.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

On Unix/Linux, a simple shell command could be used alternatively to convert all files from a given directory:

```
recode L1..UTF8 dir/*
```

It could be started via PHP's [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) as well.

Comment: Didn't know about this command. Thanks! I use Linux even as workstation, all of my local servers are on Linux. And what does L1.. in the command means?

Comment: @Starmaster: L1 is shorthand for Latin-1, the source charset.

Answer (score 2):

```
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
```

I got this line from [Cool](http://www.skoumal.net/en/making-utf-8-csv-excel/)

Comment: This is similar to [Alaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-can-i-write-a-file-in-utf-8-format/15146274#15146274).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recode recursively, and filter for type, try this:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec recode L1..UTF8 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I put all together and got easy way to convert ANSI text files to "UTF-8 No Mark":

```php
function filesToUTF8($searchdir, $convdir, $filetypes) {
  $get_files = glob($searchdir . '*{' . $filetypes . '}', GLOB_BRACE);
  foreach($get_files as $file) {
    $expl_path = explode('/', $file);
    $filename = end($expl_path);
    $get_file_content = file_get_contents($file);
    $new_file_content = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($get_file_content, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $get_file_content);
    $put_new_file = file_put_contents($convdir.$filename, $new_file_content);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
filesToUTF8('C:/Temp/', 'C:/Temp/conv_files/', 'php,txt');
```

Comment: What is "No Mark"? Without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: Why "`php,txt`"? Shouldn't it be "`php.txt`"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite useful question. I think that my solution on Windows 10 PHP 7 is rather useful for people who have yet some UTF-8 conversion trouble.

Here are my steps. The PHP script calling the following function, here in **utfsave.php** must have UTF-8 encoding itself, and this can be easily done by conversion on [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit).

In the *utfsave.php* file, we define a function calling PHP *fopen($filename, "**wb**")*, i.e., it's opened in both *w* write mode, and especially with *b* in **binary** mode.

```php
<?php
//
//  UTF-8 编码:
//
// fnc001: save string as a file in UTF-8:
// The resulting file is UTF-8 only if $strContent is,
// with French accents, Chinese ideograms, etc.
//
function entSaveAsUtf8($strContent, $filename) {
  $fp = fopen($filename, "wb");
  fwrite($fp, $strContent);
  fclose($fp);
  return True;
}

//
// 0. write UTF-8 string in fly into UTF-8 file:
//
$strContent = "My string contains UTF-8 chars ie 鱼肉酒菜 for un été en France";

$filename = "utf8text.txt";

entSaveAsUtf8($strContent, $filename);


//
// 2. convert CP936 ANSI/OEM - Chinese simplified GBK file into UTF-8 file
//
//   CP936: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows)>
//   GBK:   <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)> 
//
$strContent = file_get_contents("cp936gbktext.txt");
$strContent = mb_convert_encoding($strContent, "UTF-8", "CP936");


$filename = "utf8text2.txt";

entSaveAsUtf8($strContent, $filename);

?>
```

The content of source file *cp936gbktext.txt*:

```
>>Get-Content cp936gbktext.txt
My string contains UTF-8 chars ie 鱼肉酒菜 for un été en France 936 (ANSI/OEM - chinois simplifié GBK)
```

Running **utf8save.php** on Windows 10 PHP, thus created **utf8text.txt**, **utf8text2.txt** files will be automatically saved in UTF-8 format.

With this method, the BOM characters are not required. The BOM solution is bad because it causes troubles when we do sourcing of an SQL file for MySQL for example.

It's worth noting that I failed making work **file_put_contents($filename, utf8_encode($mystring));** for this purpose.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

If you don't know the encoding of the source file, you can list encodings with PHP:

```php
print_r(mb_list_encodings());
```

This gives a list like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => pass
  [1] => wchar
  [2] => byte2be
  [3] => byte2le
  [4] => byte4be
  [5] => byte4le
  [6] => BASE64
  [7] => UUENCODE
  [8] => HTML-ENTITIES
  [9] => Quoted-Printable
  [10] => 7bit
  [11] => 8bit
  [12] => UCS-4
  [13] => UCS-4BE
  [14] => UCS-4LE
  [15] => UCS-2
  [16] => UCS-2BE
  [17] => UCS-2LE
  [18] => UTF-32
  [19] => UTF-32BE
  [20] => UTF-32LE
  [21] => UTF-16
  [22] => UTF-16BE
  [23] => UTF-16LE
  [24] => UTF-8
  [25] => UTF-7
  [26] => UTF7-IMAP
  [27] => ASCII
  [28] => EUC-JP
  [29] => SJIS
  [30] => eucJP-win
  [31] => EUC-JP-2004
  [32] => SJIS-win
  [33] => SJIS-Mobile#DOCOMO
  [34] => SJIS-Mobile#KDDI
  [35] => SJIS-Mobile#SOFTBANK
  [36] => SJIS-mac
  [37] => SJIS-2004
  [38] => UTF-8-Mobile#DOCOMO
  [39] => UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-A
  [40] => UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-B
  [41] => UTF-8-Mobile#SOFTBANK
  [42] => CP932
  [43] => CP51932
  [44] => JIS
  [45] => ISO-2022-JP
  [46] => ISO-2022-JP-MS
  [47] => GB18030
  [48] => Windows-1252
  [49] => Windows-1254
  [50] => ISO-8859-1
  [51] => ISO-8859-2
  [52] => ISO-8859-3
  [53] => ISO-8859-4
  [54] => ISO-8859-5
  [55] => ISO-8859-6
  [56] => ISO-8859-7
  [57] => ISO-8859-8
  [58] => ISO-8859-9
  [59] => ISO-8859-10
  [60] => ISO-8859-13
  [61] => ISO-8859-14
  [62] => ISO-8859-15
  [63] => ISO-8859-16
  [64] => EUC-CN
  [65] => CP936
  [66] => HZ
  [67] => EUC-TW
  [68] => BIG-5
  [69] => CP950
  [70] => EUC-KR
  [71] => UHC
  [72] => ISO-2022-KR
  [73] => Windows-1251
  [74] => CP866
  [75] => KOI8-R
  [76] => KOI8-U
  [77] => ArmSCII-8
  [78] => CP850
  [79] => JIS-ms
  [80] => ISO-2022-JP-2004
  [81] => ISO-2022-JP-MOBILE#KDDI
  [82] => CP50220
  [83] => CP50220raw
  [84] => CP50221
  [85] => CP50222
)
```

If you cannot guess, you try one by one, as [mb_detect_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) cannot do the job easily.

Answer (score -7):

1. Open your files in windows notebook
2. Change the encoding to be an UTF-8 encoding
3. Save your file
4. Try again! :O)