# How to write a file in UTF-8 format

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml, fwrite

I have read a XML file with the `simplexml_load_file()` function. I suppose this function is well written and supports XML encodings correctly. My XML file is in UTF-8 format, i.e. it contains normal ANSI characters along with national characters with multibyte encoding.

So, now I want to write the XML file back with `fopen()` and `fwrite()`, also in UTF-8 format.

Should I perform some conversions to do that correctly?

Suppose variable `$a` contains some UTF-8 encodings. Will it be written correctly?

Comment: This has already been answered in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format Good Luck!

Comment: You don't have to go for `fopen` and `fwrite` if you're already using SimpleXML. `public mixed SimpleXMLElement::asXML ([ string $filename ] )`

Comment: I have read file with `simplexml`, but then abandoned this library and use my own arrays and structures to hold data. So, to write data I need either construct XML in memory first, or just write data into a file. Latter looks simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write file in UTF-8 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)

Answer (score 0):

if your xml is really encoded in utf8 already, then the strings produced by simplexml will be utf8 also. meaning- just write them to the file as-is.

php's interfacing with the underlying libxml is a bit funky though. Even though the xml may be utf8 encoded, make sure that the xml starts with a proper encoding declaration or it may get misinterpreted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```