# file_put_contents encoding used on web servers?

Tags: php

I am trying to use `file_put_contents` (and `file_get_contents` for that matter) with a UTF-8 `¥` following this stackoverflow post: [How to write file in UTF-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format) which uses:

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING');
```

Which wasn't really explained well, since it produces an error of:

```
mb_convert_encoding(): Illegal character encoding specified
```

So `'OLD-ENCODING'` was just a placeholder they were using.
The question I have is what encoding should I change this to? ASCII or ISO-8859-1? What encoding do most web hosts use? Does it matter?

When I open the file, I will get the symbol correctly, only if I have my notepad set with encoding UTF-8. If I open it with another character set it will show up with a "`?`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without third parameter.

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8");
```

Or `auto`:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "auto");
```

More info and examples on:
http://php.net/manual/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: ofc it works. as first programmer rule says: "make it as easy as u can" :)

Comment: I tested it with a lot of different scenarios and it worked each time. thank you, this deserves more upvotes :)

Comment: ty, but u know.. all i did - was reading 2 lines in documentation. try this next time with yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

`mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($data));`

[mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: Thanks! but that detects the encoding used on the server? Are my symbols converted to the correct server encoding?

Comment: Nope, it detects encoding on `$data`

Comment: oh so that would work for file_get_contents. What about putting it in? what encoding do web servers use?

Comment: Well then, you could just simply do `file_put_contents($file, utf8_encode($data));`

Comment: "Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8." That would mean $data which is being used on the website would need to be in ISO format and you would be storing it in UTF-8. That doesn't seem right. I think it would be file_get_contents($file, utf8_encode($data);

Comment: That's true. As I said, you could, not should.