# how to set UTF-8 on a created file

Tags: php, utf-8

how can i set charset to UTF-8 on a file created by php? i create my file like this:

```
if(!file_exists("games/".strtolower($dir)."/index.php")) {
        $create_index = fopen("games/".strtolower($dir)."/index.php", "w");
        $name = $row['name'];
        $content  = mb_convert_encoding($content,'UTF-8');
        $string = "
        <?php
        include '../../config.php';
        include('../../default_theme.php');
        setTitle(\"".$name."\");
        show(\"".$name."\");
        ";
        fwrite($create_index, $content);
        fwrite($create_index, $string);
        fclose($create_index);
    }
```

but then ä, ö and ü are displayed as ?�

thanks for ur help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format

Comment: doesn't work, because in my created file i do a mysql query:

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM forum_categorys WHERE owner = '$cur_id'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '<li><h1>'.$row["name"].'</h1><span class="cat_desc">'.$row["description"].'</span></li>';
        }

                                  
and there are all ü,ä,ü displayed as ?

Comment: Are you displaying it as HTML?

Comment: no, im displaying it with php as echo 'äüö'; @R2D2

Comment: There are no non-latin characters in your PHP or SQL query code.  Do you mean that the characters show incorrectly when displayed on your web page after being retrieved from your database?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the values of `$row['name']` and `$content` before they are used in your code snippet above.

Comment: i insert following line: mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES utf8"); and it worked for me :D