# how can I save as "UTF-8 with BOM" encoding?

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding, utf-8

I'm generating csv file but it save as "UTF-8 without BOM"

**how can I save as "UTF-8 with BOM" ?**

I'm using following header in codeigniter

```
 header('Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write file in UTF-8 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already a duplicate of [How can I output a UTF-8 CSV in PHP that Excel will read properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348802/how-can-i-output-a-utf-8-csv-in-php-that-excel-will-read-properly)

However you need to include a [Byte Order Mark](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM). This can be done in this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601168/678611

```
<?php

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<a filename>.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // Byte Order Mark
echo $the_csv_file_content;
exit();

?>
```