# how do i force to set charset while writing to a file setting charset 1256 in php

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

how do i force to set charset while writing to a file setting charset 1256 in php
i have some data in sql which reads as ÇáÓáÇã Úáíßã æÑÍãå Çááå æÈÑßÇÊå and i am trying to convert it into correct (Arabic) format charset Windows-1256

my code is

```
$text = "ÇáÓáÇã Úáíßã æÑÍãå Çááå æÈÑßÇÊå";
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
```

it saves the data same as it is although it display in correct format on browser
i want to save it into text or maybe CSV as
السلام عليكم ورحمه الله وبركاته يا اخوان هذا الفيروس
which is its correct format

Comment: try using mb_convert_string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write file in UTF-8 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `iconv()` ?

```
echo iconv('WINDOWS-1256', 'UTF-8', "ÇáÓáÇã Úáíßã æÑÍãå Çááå æÈÑßÇÊå");
```

Comment: it worked fine however if i put this file into sql table field it becomes more gabrish like Ø§Ù„Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø¹Ù„ÙŠÙƒÙ… ÙˆØ±Ø­Ù…Ù‡ Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ can you help please

Comment: It might be related to encoding of your db. I will suggest to check encoding of file which you are importing into db and also make sure your encoding of dbare correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use iconv() function.

Example:

```
fwrite( $file, iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256', $text) );
```

From UTF-8 to Windows-1256

Comment: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in //path

Comment: You need know, what charset in your file.
And correct iconv() first parameter 'UTF-8' on your charset.

Comment: i open up the gabrish into notepad++ and it only displays correct Araic when i chose Encoding -> Character set -> Arabic -> windows-1256 on all other options it do not displays well so i assume it is 1256

Comment: what charset set in the begining?

Comment: reordring UTF-8', 'Windows-1256' to vise helped as Tomasz Turkowski answerd thank you very much